# Develop a trigger to update "MC Commercial Setup" with Account Record Type information when a new customer is created in SF

Tags: trigger

For Account, we have some record types defined like 'small organisation', 'large organisation', 'business' etc. There are 2 millions records.

Requirement: I need write Apex Trigger while creating new Account to update custom field MC_Commercial_Setup__c with the record type name only if record type name (RecordType.name) is 'small organisation' or 'large organisation'.

Note: It needs to trigger while creating new records and update MC_Commercial_Setup__c field with record type value.

I tried to accomplish this task with the code below but it's not updating the Filed MC_Commercial_Setup__c  :

```
trigger UpdateNewAccount on Account (before insert) {

   List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();

    for(Account acnt : Trigger.new)
    {
        if( acnt.RecordType.Name=='Large Organisation' || acnt.RecordType.Name=='SME/SOHO Organisation'){
            acnt.MC_Commercial_Setup__c  =   acnt.RecordType.Name;
              accList.add(acnt);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access parent fields (RecordType.Name not available, but you can access RecordTypeId) in trigger - you need to fetch them from DB.

You should use the next query:

```
SELECT Id, RecordType.Name FROM Account
```

or better [get record type info from Schema](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221854/retrieve-record-type-developer-name-in-trigger)

Moreover, I would like to recommend check [Apex triggers best practices](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers)

Comment: Yes but using Schema,we need to give Record type Name also in that fuction. But we dont know what user will select record type

Comment: you can use Account.RecordTypeId to get record name from Schema

rtMap.get(a.RecordTypeId).getDeveloperName()